# GPS Provider returns null values

Tags: android

When Reading Lat&Lang Values using GPS Provider returning null values when GPS enabled but after 10 to 15 seconds getting lat&lang values perfectly. How to get lat&lang values for first time after enabling GPS.

Comment: It takes time to fetch the exact location. You can show a progress dialog till data is loaded

Comment: check this condtion before using map instance `if (googleMap != null )` .

Comment: I am not using map here

Comment: Can we see code ,which you are trying yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPS provider is returning null values just after enabling the GPS because your GPS receiver just started listening to data sent from GPS satellites. This means that the Latitude and Longitude will keep null values until your GPS receiver get a new location.
Notice that your LocationManager has a method called 'getLastKnownLocation(String provider)' as mentioned in the link [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)). This method will return the last saved GPS location (if there is), this means you're not going to have null values, however, disabling your device GPS will remove this info and you will get null values after enabling it as usual.

What I do exactly in your situation is :
- Save the last user location before the app is terminated (using SharedPreferences or other storage methods)
- Use the getLastKnownLocation(String provider) value if it's not null, otherwise, load the last saved user location.